# Remove the 'hover' function on a clicked checkbox in a group

Tags: jquery

I am trying to  Remove the 'hover' function on a clicked checkbox in a group. I can do it on all the checkbox in the group by:

```
$(document).off('hover', '.myClass .leftSpan');
```

Is there a way to just remove it from the clicked checkbox?

The 'hover' function puts the hover there in the first place, the click is intended to start populating a record set but I want:

```
$(document).on('hover', '.myClass .leftSpan', function () {
    var parID = $(this).prev('input').prop('id')
    $('#lblOutput').text(parID);
    GetSites(parID, 'false');
    GetGroupMetadataFromGroupID(parID);
});
```

This is the click function:

```
$(document).on('click', '.myClass .leftSpan', function () {
    var parID = $(this).prev('input').prop('id')
    $('#lblOutput').text(parID);
    GetSites(parID, 'false');
    GetGroupMetadataFromGroupID(parID);
    $(document).off('hover', parID);
});
```

But it does not work. I will need to do it to any that are clicked. This could be from just one to all being clicked.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: try `unbind`.  Possibly `$(this).unbind('hover');`

Comment: Nope, this didn't work, sorry...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution really. I did not find a satisfactory way of removing the hover attribute so I reconfigured the code testing if the checkbox was checked and if it was, miss out the code that calls the list of places related to the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a namespaced event, it'll be easier and more readable.

```
var myhover = function () { ... }
$(document).on('hover.myhover', '.myClass .leftSpan', myhover) //on
$(document).off('hover.myhover') //off
```

In any case, unless your elements are direct children of `body` you should be using the closest static parent instead of `document` for best performance.

Answer (score 0):

`$(document).off("hover", ".myClass:checked");` ?

or even better

`$(".myClass:checked").off("hover")`

Comment: Thanks, but this removes the hover from all the check boxes, not just the clicked one.

Comment: By "the clicked one" do you mean a checkbox that is checked, or just one that is clicked? If it's the first, then my answer should work. `$(".myClass:checked")` will give you all elements of class `myClass` that are checked. See http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

Comment: I want to remove the hover from the checkbox that I click and therefore checking. I don;t want any other checkboxes to be affected by this. To clarify what I am trying to do, I want to be able to hvoer over the checkboxes, which each give a list of different places. When a check box is checked, a list is populated by the places referred to by that checkbox. The user can continue hovering over the remaining checkboxes and check another checkbox, which in turn adds the places to the list and so on. Similarly, if a checkbox is subsequently unchecked, the places would be removed from the list.